# Option to automatically shutdown at GRUB without user input?

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot, grub, luks, shutdown

I have a laptop that dual boots Arch and Windows 10. My boot select is set to a GRUB screen where I'm given a few seconds to change my selection (default is Arch) until it boots to a LUKS unlock screen. Often times I'll leave the laptop on my Windows partition and it'll decide to reboot, causing GRUB to select the Arch partition and then sit at the LUKS password input for hours (which makes the laptop run hard for some reason).
Is there an option within GRUB to automatically shutdown if a selection is not entered in time, say 30 seconds? If not, is this something I can set with LUKS?
Thanks!

Comment: You can add a grub menu entry for shutdown then make that the default.  I will try to post the entry and config code when I get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably should have looked harder before asking :-)
This is what I did:

1. Backed up /boot/grub/grub.cfg
2. Edited the timeout to 15 seconds from 5 to give me enough time
3. Added a menu entry at the top (before Arch Linux) with the setting:

   menuentry "Shutdown" {
   halt
   }
4. Saved grub.cfg

Now whenever the computer boots I have 15 seconds to hit down arrow to select Arch or Windows, else it selects shutdown.

Comment: No problem glad it worked out for you.